# "I have submitted the application" is it a right sentence?

Tags: grammaticality, perfect-constructions

I want to respond my counterpart in another location that I submitted required application or form and request him to review the application and let me know in case of any additional information.  My doubt is "I have" or "I had" to begin sentence with.

Answer (score 5):

> I **have submitted** the application, and await your feedback.

is correct. Present perfect tense is used, because the actions related to your application (review and decision) are in the present time frame.

Past perfect would be correct if those actions were completed:

> I **had submitted** the application, but the position was already filled.

Answer (score -1):

"I have" is correct. Present Perfect tense.

Answer (score -1):

The sentence is correct.
The selection of the word is good.
Submitted- denotes humbleness and respect for the organisation or the individual who is the addressee here.